# Правильно ли я добавлять в 2-ой словарь?

Tags: c#

```
public class Users {
    public Dictionary < ulong, Dictionary < string, string >> CachePlayer;

    public Users Default() {
        CachePlayer = new Dictionary < ulong, Dictionary < string, string >> ();
        return this;
    }
}
```

Добавление:

```
public static CFG.Users Users = new CFG.Users();

DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer.Add(player.Uid);
DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer[player.Uid].Add("Username", player.Name);
DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer[player.Uid].Add("Ip", player.Ip);
DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer[player.Uid].Add("Health", player.Health.ToString());
DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer[player.Uid].Add("TimeOnline", player.TimeOnline.ToString());
```

Comment: А зачем вложенный словарь? Создайте класс, храните его экземпляры в словаре.

Comment: `DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer.Add(player.Uid);` - компилируется?

Comment: @Сергей можете дать пример такой реализации?

Comment: @Igor - опа неа - просит 2 параметр

Comment: Вот и ответ на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Мне не ясно, что вы делаете и зачем, но ошибка у вас в том, что вы пытаетесь добавить в словарь ключ без значения

```
DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer.Add(player.Uid);
```

Замените на

```
DC4_CORE.Loader.Users.CachePlayer.Add(player.Uid, new Dictionary<string, string>());
```